# How to add style to a MVC View validation?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Im beginner for the MVC, I want to style my MVC validation how can i do it?

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    @Html.ListBoxFor(a => a.QRefIds, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.QltyRfs, "QReferenceId", "QReferenceCode"), new { Class = "form-control", title = "Select Feeder List", style = "width:575px;height:50px; margin-top:6px;font-size:small;" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.QRefIds)
</div>
```

Comment: I believe it outputs a span with the class error (or something like that) If you [inspect the HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12428374/542251) you should be able to see what I mean

Comment: `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` generates a `<span>` with either `class="field-validation-valid"` or `class="field-validation-error"` so you can just use css to style it based on the class name

Comment: Thanks for the help, understood 
.field-validation-error {
    color: red;
    font-size: 10.5px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

Comment: this might help:http://developmentpassion.blogspot.de/2015/10/custom-validation-message-helper-in.html

Comment: That link is too much unnecessary work for the simple thing you wanna do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The validation helpers generate bunch of `span` with a class `field-validation-error` you can change that using CSS:

```
.field-validation-error {

   background-color:white;

   border-radius:4px;

   border: solid 1px #333;

   display: block;

   position: absolute;

   top:0; right:0; left:0;

   text-align:right;

}
```

You can also style up `input-validation-error` when there is a validation error for inputs:

```
.input-validation-error{ background: pink; border: 1px solid red; }
```