# Reduce hight of frame in flexdashboard / storyboard

Tags: r, storyboard, markdown, flexdashboard

Im working on a flexdashboard / storyboard where I would like to reduce the hight for each of the frames. Is that possible?

Example code:

````
---
title: "Flex"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```
G1 {.storyboard}
===================================================

### Frame 1

Some text and code

### Frame 2

Some text and code

G2
===================================================

### Row 1

### Row 2
````

I.e. remove the empty area as below:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The controls are in the css. Two things to change - height of the box (first css), and height of the page arrows (second css). The 'height' variable needs changing in both.

````
    ---
    title: "Flex"
    output: 
      flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
        orientation: columns
        vertical_layout: fill
    ---

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    library(flexdashboard)
    ```
    G1 {.storyboard}
    ===================================================

    ### Frame 1

    Some text and code

    ### Frame 2

    Some text and code

    G2
    ===================================================

    ### Row 1

    ### Row 2

    <style>

    .storyboard-nav .sbframelist {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 94%;
        height: 50px;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-shadow: none;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
    }

    .storyboard-nav .sbnext, .storyboard-nav .sbprev {
        float: left;
        width: 2%;
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 50px;
    }

    </style>
````

Comment: When you're inspecting the element using Google Chrome, in the styles tab, there's a "toggle element state" button.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428364/how-to-inspect-css-element-using-chrome