# button element looks small on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular6

I have a simple input and button. The button looks fine on the actual computer regardless of screen size. The first screenshot is what it looks like from the mobile view in the dev tools. However, when I actually visit the site on my phone I get the second picture. As you can see the button is shorter than it was on the desktop settings. Any ideas on how to address this?

[what it looks like on desktop and should look like on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltARQ.png)

[What it actually looks like on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DrTt.jpg)

```css
.input-field {
  width: 370px;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  height: 35px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  @media (max-width: 500px) {
      width: 250px;
  }

}
.email-input {
  display: flex;
  height: 35px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 60px;

}
.email-button {
  height: 37px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  background-color: #50AE54;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  @media (max-width: 600px) {
      width: 75px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="email-input">
     <input type="text" class="input-field" [(ngModel)]="email_address" placeholder="Email me for updates" />
     <button class="email-button" (click)="subscribe()">Send</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to both the `input`, and the `button`, and set height to 100% on both as well

Comment: It is working fine on android chrome but not on safari or ios chrome.

Comment: Thats good to know @Ammar

Comment: I tried adding box-sizing but it doesn't seem to make a difference @user184994

Answer (score 1):

Add 
`*{ box-sizing: border-box }` 
to css.
This fixes the issue.

Comment: to what class? I added it to the button but it didn't help.

Comment: @tyler you may need to set the height of the input and button to 100% as well

Comment: @tyler It is working on my safari and chrome. Screenshot: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RTgIhj6Zluz-5Ln-hdaqaDdk4z9CZO1U
Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/ammarbinfaisal/full/djGpJw/

Comment: This worked! Thank you for attaching the codepen that was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code and styling in codepen and it looks the same across different devices.

As I can see, not only the button styling got affected, but some of the rest as well: the text padding within the input box.

Perhaps the parent styling is affecting this component's styling?

(If you're using Chrome to debug, you can easily inspect the element - [How to inspect CSS element using Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428364/how-to-inspect-css-element-using-chrome))

Comment: It looks the same accross devices if you are just on a computer using chromes dev tools. But if you run it on the physical phone itself it doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

> you can create responsive web pages using bootstrap easily check this
>   links

[Bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/#available-classes)

[check this also](https://www.sitepoint.com/build-responsive-bootstrap-website/)

and also check

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

for responsive web designing

Comment: did u install bootstrap to your angular project

Comment: I don't to use bootstrap

Comment: try this if u like https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/how-to-build-responsive-layouts-with-bootstrap-4-and-angular-6-cfbb108d797b